# Meaning of stable $CP^2$

Tags: group-theory, notation, automorphism-group, grassmannian

I came across the following phrase in arXiv:1903.08904

> ....in order to have a stable $CP^2$ , i.e., one in which all the
>   automorphism group is fixed...

Can anyone explain to me what one means by a stable $CP^2$? It is mentioned in the phrase itself, but I do not know what one means by a fixed automorphism group. It must be some usual mathematical terminology which I am not aware of, so please help.

Answer (score 0):

Stability normally refers to stability under some action. Given some homomorphism $T: \text{End}(\mathbb{C}P^2) \to \text{End}(\mathbb{C}P^2)$, we would say that $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{C}P^2)$ is stable under $T$ (or $T$-stable) if $T: \text{Aut}(\mathbb{C}P^2) \to \text{Aut}(\mathbb{C}P^2)$.

Comment: What is T ? Is it just any action which preserves $Aut(CP^2)$ ?

Comment: $T$ is just some homomorphism. If $T$ maps $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{C}P^2)$ to itself, then $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{C}P^2)$ is stable under $T$. So, yes if $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{C}P^2)$ is stable under $T$, then $T$ preserves $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{C}P^2)$.